# Shortest path in maze

Tags: java, algorithm, pathfinding

Please help review my code.

```
public class Maze {
    // question: give a maze. Find shortest path from left top corner to right bottom corner.
    // 1 is wall. cannot go thru.
    int minFoundLen = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    int m = 0;
    int n = 0;
    public void findPath(int[][] mazePlan){
        if(mazePlan.length == 0) return;

        m = mazePlan.length;
        n = mazePlan[0].length;
        int[][] path = new int[m][n];


        helper(mazePlan, 0, 0, 0,path);
        System.out.println("shortest path is " + minFoundLen);
    }

    private void helper(int[][] maze, int x, int y, int pathLen,int[][] path){
        if(x < 0 || y < 0 || x >= m || y >= n){
            return;
        }
        if(path[x][y]!=0){
            return;
        }
        if(maze[x][y] != 0){
            return;
        }
        if(x == m-1 && y == n-1){
            minFoundLen = Math.min(minFoundLen, pathLen);
            return;
        }
        path[x][y] = 1;
        helper(maze, x+1,y,pathLen+1,path);
        helper(maze, x-1,y,pathLen+1,path);
        helper(maze, x,y+1,pathLen+1,path);
        helper(maze, x,y-1,pathLen+1,path);
        path[x][y] = 0;

    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int[][] mazePlan = {
        {0,1,0,0,0},
        {0,0,0,1,0},
        {0,0,0,0,0},
        {1,1,1,0,0},
        {0,0,0,0,0}
        };

        Maze maze = new Maze();
        maze.findPath(mazePlan);
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks like a weird, informal implementation of Dijkstra’s Algorithm.  Is that what you were trying to achieve?

Answer (score 3):

**1 Algorithm**

This is not Dijkstra's algorithm and that is not breadth-first search either. It's an unweighted brute-force shortest path algorithm. Basically, you generate all possible paths from the source node (top-left cell) to the target node (bottom-right) cell.

On my machine (2.5 GHz) the following maze takes about 300 milliseconds to solve:

```
int[][] mazePlan = {
    {0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0},
    {0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0},
    {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
    {1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0},
    {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
    {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
};
```

**2 Coding**

You should rename the fields **`minFoundLen`**, **`n`** and  **`m`** to something like **`shortestPathLengthSoFar`** **`mazeHeight`** and **`mazeWidth`**, respectively. Also, you do not have to initialize **`m`** and **`n`** to zero; Java initializes integer fields to zero by default.

Taking into consideration what you do with **`int[][] path`**, I suggest you rename it to **`boolean[][] visited`**.

```
System.out.println("shortest path is " + minFoundLen);
```

It's not funky to **print** the result of an algorithm to standard output; instead, return the actual result, and let the caller of the algorithm do whatever he/she wants.

You can always store **`maze`** and **`visited`** in the fields of your object; that way, **`helper`** asks only three arguments instead of five.

```
if(path[x][y]!=0){
    return;
}
```

1. There should be *one space before and after a binary operator*.
2. There should be *one space before and after a parenthesized expression*.

So, combining the two above points you should rather write:

```
if (path[x][y] != 0) {
    return;
}
```

You should also separate "logical blocks" by a single empty line; like this:

```
    if (maze[x][y] != 0) {
        return;
    }

    if (x == m - 1 && y == n - 1) {
        minFoundLen = Math.min(minFoundLen, pathLen);
        return;
    }

    path[x][y] = 1;

    helper(maze, x + 1, y, pathLen + 1, path);
    helper(maze, x - 1, y, pathLen + 1, path);
    helper(maze, x, y + 1, pathLen + 1, path);
    helper(maze, x, y - 1, pathLen + 1, path);

    path[x][y] = 0;
```

And don't forget that you should have a space **after any comma**.

**3 Alternative impelmentation**

I have gathered all the points and used breadth-first search for solving the maze. That it how it might look:

**Maze.java**:

```
import java.awt.Point;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;

public class Maze {

    private static final boolean CELL_OCCUPIED = true;

    private final boolean[][] maze;

    public Maze(final boolean[][] maze) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(maze, "The input maze is null.");

        final int numberOfRows = maze.length;

        if (numberOfRows == 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("The input maze is empty.");
        }

        int numberOfColumns = 0;

        for (int row = 0; row < maze.length; ++row) {
            numberOfColumns = Math.max(numberOfColumns, maze[row].length);
        }

        this.maze = new boolean[numberOfRows][numberOfColumns];

        for (int row = 0; row < numberOfRows; ++row) {
            for (int column = 0;
                     column < Math.min(numberOfColumns, maze[row].length);
                     column++) {
                this.maze[row][column] = maze[row][column];
            }
        }
    }

    public int getWidth() {
        return maze[0].length;
    }

    public int getHeight() {
        return maze.length;
    }

    public boolean cellIsFree(final Point p) {
        return cellIsFree(p.x, p.y);
    }

    public boolean cellIsWithinMaze(final Point p) {
        return p.x >= 0 && p.x < getWidth() && p.y >= 0 && p.y < getHeight();
    }

    public boolean cellIsTraversible(final Point p) {
        return cellIsWithinMaze(p) && cellIsFree(p);
    }

    public boolean cellIsFree(final int x, final int y) {
        checkXCoordinate(x);
        checkYCoordinate(y);
        return maze[y][x] != CELL_OCCUPIED;
    }

    public String withPath(final List<Point> path) {
        final char[][] matrix = new char[getHeight()][getWidth()];

        for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; ++i) {
            for (int j = 0; j < matrix[0].length; ++j) {
                matrix[i][j] = maze[i][j] ? 'x' : '.';
            }
        }

        for (final Point p : path) {
            matrix[p.y][p.x] = 'o';
        }

        final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        sb.append(new String(matrix[0]));

        for (int i = 1; i < matrix.length; ++i) {
            sb.append('\n');
            sb.append(new String(matrix[i]));
        }

        return sb.toString();
    }

    private void checkXCoordinate(final int x) {
        if (x < 0) {
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException(
                    "The x-coordinate is negative: " + x + ".");
        }

        if (x >= maze[0].length) {
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException(
                    "The x-coordinate is too large (" + x + 
                    "). The amount of columns in this maze is " + 
                    maze[0].length + ".");
        }
    }

    private void checkYCoordinate(final int y) {
        if (y < 0) {
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException(
                    "The y-coordinate is negative: " + y + ".");
        }

        if (y >= maze.length) {
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException(
                    "The y-coordinate is too large (" + y + 
                    "). The amount of rows in this maze is " + 
                    maze.length + ".");
        }
    }
}
```

**MazePathFinder.java**:

```
package review;

import java.awt.Point;
import java.util.ArrayDeque;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.Queue;

public class MazePathFinder {

    private Maze maze;
    private Point source;
    private Point target;
    private boolean[][] visited;
    private Map<Point, Point> parents;

    public MazePathFinder() {}

    private MazePathFinder(final Maze maze, 
                           final Point source, 
                           final Point target) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(maze, "The input maze is null.");
        Objects.requireNonNull(source, "The source node is null.");
        Objects.requireNonNull(target, "The target node is null.");

        this.maze = maze;
        this.source = source;
        this.target = target;

        checkSourceNode();
        checkTargetNode();

        this.visited = new boolean[maze.getHeight()][maze.getWidth()];
        this.parents = new HashMap<>();
        this.parents.put(source, null);
    }

    public List<Point> findPath(final Maze maze, 
                                final Point source, 
                                final Point target) {
        return new MazePathFinder(maze, source, target).compute();
    }

    private List<Point> compute() {
        final Queue<Point> queue = new ArrayDeque<>();
        final Map<Point, Integer> distances = new HashMap<>();

        queue.add(source);
        distances.put(source, 0);

        while (!queue.isEmpty()) {
            // Removes the head of the queue.
            final Point current = queue.remove();

            if (current.equals(target)) {
                return constructPath();
            }

            for (final Point child : generateChildren(current)) {
                if (!parents.containsKey(child)) {
                    parents.put(child, current);
                    // Appends 'child' to the end of this queue.
                    queue.add(child);
                }
            }
        }

        // null means that the target node is not reachable
        // from the source node.
        return null;
    }

    private List<Point> constructPath() {
        Point current = target;
        final List<Point> path = new ArrayList<>();

        while (current != null) {
            path.add(current);
            current = parents.get(current);
        }

        Collections.<Point>reverse(path);
        return path;
    }

    private Iterable<Point> generateChildren(final Point current) {
        final Point north = new Point(current.x, current.y - 1);
        final Point south = new Point(current.x, current.y + 1);
        final Point west = new Point(current.x - 1, current.y);
        final Point east = new Point(current.x + 1, current.y);

        final List<Point> childList = new ArrayList<>(4);

        if (maze.cellIsTraversible(north)) {
            childList.add(north);
        }

        if (maze.cellIsTraversible(south)) {
            childList.add(south);
        }

        if (maze.cellIsTraversible(west)) {
            childList.add(west);
        }

        if (maze.cellIsTraversible(east)) {
            childList.add(east);
        }

        return childList;
    }

    private void checkSourceNode() {
        checkNode(source, 
                  "The source node (" + source + ") is outside the maze. " +
                  "The width of the maze is " + maze.getWidth() + " and " +
                  "the height of the maze is " + maze.getHeight() + ".");

        if (!maze.cellIsFree(source.x, source.y)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                    "The source node (" + source + ") is at a occupied cell.");
        }
    }

    private void checkTargetNode() {
        checkNode(target, 
                  "The target node (" + target + ") is outside the maze. " +
                  "The width of the maze is " + maze.getWidth() + " and " +
                  "the height of the maze is " + maze.getHeight() + ".");

        if (!maze.cellIsFree(target.x, target.y)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                    "The target node (" + target + ") is at a occupied cell.");
        }
    }

    private void checkNode(final Point node, final String errorMessage) {
        if (node.x < 0 
                || node.x >= maze.getWidth()
                || node.y < 0
                || node.y >= maze.getHeight()) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(errorMessage);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[][] mazePlan = {
            {0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0},
            {0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0},
            {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
            {1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0},
            {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
            {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
        };

        boolean[][] maze2 = new boolean[mazePlan.length][mazePlan[0].length];

        for (int i = 0; i < maze2.length; ++i) {
            for (int j = 0; j < maze2[i].length; ++j) {
                maze2[i][j] = mazePlan[i][j] > 0;
            }
        }

        final Maze maze = new Maze(maze2);
        final Point source = new Point(); // Same as new Point(0, 0):
        final Point target = new Point(7, 5);


        long startTime = System.nanoTime();
        final List<Point> path = new MazePathFinder().findPath(maze, 
                                                               source, 
                                                               target);
        long endTime  = System.nanoTime();

        System.out.printf("BFS maze finder in %d milliseconds.\n",
                          (endTime - startTime) / 1_000_000L);

        System.out.println("Shortest path length: " + (path.size() - 1));
        System.out.println(maze.withPath(path));
    }
}
```

Hope that helps.